# Inserting, deleting and updating data rows on jtable

Tags: java, jtable, edit

Greetings from Hellas !.!.!
A screen from my project is: 
A jTable, 5 jTextFields with 5 jLabels and 4 jbuttons.
By clicking the 1st button, i want to insert a row to the jTable,  with the values from the jTextFields. By clicking the 2nd button, i want to delete a row, with data from jTable. The 3rd is about refreshing and showing, the last inserted records on the jTable. The last button, the most simple of all and the one that i'm sure it works, is for getting back in the main screen of my application. Now i don't know how to make the other 3 buttons to work as i am a newbie in java programming and this is my first serious step.. Anyone who can give some useful tips or links to read from them it will be so helpful... Thank you so much for your time...!!! 
And this is my source code:

```
package Forms;

/*import java.beans.Beans;
import static java.rmi.Naming.list;
import static org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.utility.CollectionTools.list;*/


/**
*
* @author Λάζαρος
*/
public class Customers extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private Object entityManager;
    private Object list;
    private Object query;
    private Object rowId;
    private String sql;


    /**
     * Creates new form Customers
     */
    public Customers() {
        /*if (!Beans.isDesignTime()) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        }*/
        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Πίνακας Πελατών");

        jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Κωδικός Πελάτη", "Όνομα", "Επώνυμο ", "Τηλέφωνο", "E-mail "
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Κωδικός Πελάτη:");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Όνομα:");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Επώνυμο:");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Τηλέφωνο:");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("E-mail:");

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N

        jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N

        jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N

        jTextField4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N

        jTextField5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Διαγραφή");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("Αποθήκευση");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setText("Ανανέωση");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton5.setText("Πίσω");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 333, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 333, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 333, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 333, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 333, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 137, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        //Back button !!
        this.setVisible(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        // Delete button !!
       rowId = Πελάτες.getValue();


    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       //Insert button !! 

    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      // Refresh button !!  
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments

     */
    public static void main(String args[])  {

        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        //</editor-fold>

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Customers().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    /*private void PreparedStatement(String insert_into_ΠελάτεςΚωδικόςΠελάτηΌνομαΕπών) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }*/


}
```

Comment: You have a lot of generated code which makes it hard to read or debug. Is there any code you actually wrote yourself, or did you just generate everything? If so, I'd recommend you forget about the GUI creator and read a Swing tutorial.

Comment: i've tried  by myself to use code examples that i found here in this forum but it didn't worked at all and now the code that remained is the generated

Comment: Hi.  Break out the table model into a subclass and expose methods to add/delete rows to the table model.  Check out [JTable delete multiple rows with AbstractTableModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867200/jtable-delete-multiple-rows-with-abstracttablemodel).